# I am getting an Error everytime i am trying to execute the following command line in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have downloaded A project from [GitHub](https://github.com/n76/lacells-creator) in the usage section there is this command:

```
API_KEY=xxx ./lacells-creator -d -i -c648 -m -p
```

It's supposed to download source files, process them, and upload to the phone everytime I run this command.

However, after getting the API KEY from [here](http://wiki.opencellid.org/wiki/How_to_join) and running the command I receive this error.

> getopt: illegal option -- o

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author apparently used a `getopt` option which isn't supported by the version you have installed locally.

Given that the script is written in Bash, rewriting the script to use the built-in `getopts` would probably improve portability.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt#Shell